# Why is my Unity C# function returning NaN values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to calculate gravity between bodies using the following script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const float gravity = 10;
    public float mass = 10f;
    public bool active = true;
    public Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public Transform transform;
    GameObject[] otherObjs;
    Gravity[] otherGravities;

    void Start () {
        rigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        transform = gameObject.transform;
        otherObjs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Body");
        otherGravities = new Gravity[otherObjs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < otherObjs.Length; i++)
        {
            otherGravities[i] = otherObjs[i].GetComponent<Gravity>();
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        rigidbody.AddForce(CalculateGravity());
    }

    Vector3 CalculateGravity () {
        Vector3 finalGravity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        foreach (Gravity current in otherGravities) {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, current.transform.position);
            Vector3 unNormalDirection = transform.position - current.transform.position;
            Vector3 direction = unNormalDirection.normalized;
            Vector3 gravitationalPull = ((mass * current.mass) / (distance * distance)) * direction;
            finalGravity += gravitationalPull;
        }
        return finalGravity;
    }
}
```

When running the code, I get the following error

```
rigidbody.force assign attempt for 'Sun' is not valid. Input force is { NaN, NaN, NaN }.
UnityEngine.Rigidbody:AddForce (UnityEngine.Vector3)
Gravity:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/Gravity.cs:27)
```

I get this for both objects in the scene.
I can't seem to figure out why the function is returning NaN's, I've double checked that it is not dividing by zero. If you have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: If an expression is fed with a nan variable, it will evaluate to nan

Comment: @Tarik do you know which variable is NaN? I can't find one.

Comment: It could be transform.position or any other. You need to put some if statements all over to catch the culprit.

Comment: Are you including a body in the objects to gravitate itself toward when you do `otherObjs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Body");` then getting a 0 distance to divide by when calculating the gravity?

Comment: @Terik I see, what I have been doing is using a test variable return a specific value, instead of the final one, and it is not the distance, either mass, or the direction (though I had to do a revision because it was reversed) and now I am testing the gravitational pull variable and it threw the error for the sun, but not for the planet. Any idea why?

Comment: @moreON That might be the issue, upon testing with an if statement, the current body is included in it's other objs array, do you know any way to remove it from the array?

Comment: The absolute easiest will be just to test for 0 distance when calculating the gravities, and skip that object at that point. But perhaps more ideally, you can test if `gameObject == otherObjs[i]` - I assume that reference equality is the right test here, but I don't know your application - when setting up `otherGravities` and not include it at that point. You'll have to know whether `gameObject` has the `"Body"` tag or not to work out how long to make the array. I'll try to make this an answer.

Comment: You say that you've double checked that it is not dividing by zero.  Are you sure you're sure?  Maybe you should double-check that you've double-checked. 
 `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Body");` will include itself.  I think the name `otherObjs` alone is cause for alarm, because it's not just "other" objects, it's also "this" object, which will cause `Vector3.Distance(transform.position, current.transform.position);` to run even when `current` is this object, thus resulting in a `distance` of zero and hence a division by zero and a NaN value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm basing this on a few assumptions. It looks like you're probably calculating gravitational attraction to bodies from themselves, with a distance of `0`, and dividing by that `0`.

In the line `otherObjs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Body");` you're getting all objects with the tag `"Body"` which probably includes objects you're applying gravity to. I'd try to filter them something like this:

```
    void Start () {
        rigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        transform = gameObject.transform;
        otherObjs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Body");
        int otherGravitiesLength = otherObjs.Length;
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("Body")) {
            //Must exclude this object from its own other gravities list.
            //So don't include it in the length of that array.
            otherGravitiesLength = otherGravitiesLength - 1;
        }
        otherGravities = new Gravity[otherGravitiesLength];
        int insertIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < otherObjs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (otherObjs[i] != gameObject) {
                otherGravities[insertIndex++] = otherObjs[i].GetComponent<Gravity>();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've never used Unity, so I'm making some guesses about the API from context, and a tiny bit of googling, so this answer may need some repair.

If it is possible for two distinct bodies that gravitationally attract to be in the same position, then you should probably still also test for a zero distance and handle that differently within `CalculateGravity`

Comment: While I have the same guess .. why make the list so complicated? You could instead of filtering within `Start` simply rather skip according item in the `foreach` loop later `if(current == this) continue;` .. would be a single line change ^^ In general both could be done in one go using `Linq` and do `otherGravities = GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("Body").Where(obj => obj != gameObject).Select(obj => obj.GetComponent<Gravity>()).ToArray();`

Comment: @derHugo based on the question having no linq, using arrays for everything, and me not using Unity, I don't know if the API _has_ linq there available to use. I can certainly understand that a framework for game development might strip back some features. So I kept the code as close to how the original question was written as I could. But if you can make it better please press that edit button, I would appreciate it.